# ajax call produces [Object object] with json

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, ajax

my ajax call in my HTML produces a [Object object] instead of a desired JavaScript object with some values (eg. id, ordersitems etc) 
Why is that? and how can i solve this?

ajax call is the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    console.log("BEREIT ZUM SOP");
    var sum = 0;

    // artikel in von session holen über sbservice
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/HandyHammer/rest/shoppingbasket",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json" 
        })
        .done(function(responseData) {

            console.log(responseData);
            alert(responseData);
```

the GET method called is the following (toJSON method is a self written method producing a JSON format):

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response GetShoppingBasket() {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (session.getAttribute("basket") == null) {
        System.out.println("kein warenkorb GET session: lege neue an");
        session.setAttribute("basket", new Orders());
    }

    Orders basket = (Orders)session.getAttribute("basket");
    System.out.println("Session geladen");

    System.out.println("tostring " + basket);
    System.out.println("tojson " + basket.toJSON());
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(basket.toJSON()).build();
}
```

**Edit 1**
console.dir shows following:
[console.dir output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aNfD.jpg)

this is what i wanted. But how can i access the properties now? like for example to output a dynamic table with afforementioned properties?

Comment: Could you try with `console.dir(responseData);` instead of `console.log(responseData);`?

Comment: Please add your self written toJSON method. Also could you add the console output.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/HandyHammer/rest/shoppingbasket must be returning a json if it's not... that's is the problem ...you try it alone... and shows ...a JSON

Comment: console.dir output added. but how can i access them?

Comment: okay it works now thank you!